# Resource folder for Samsung Galaxy Tab E SM-T561 Tablet

Tags: android, resources

[image]Hi I have developed android application for mobile, now we have the application to to Samsung Galaxy Tab E SM-T561 Tablet which is the resolution of 1280*800. Please anyone suggest me the below requirements:

1. layout folder name.
2. drawable folder name.
3. strings values, color and dimen values etc...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Easiest way is to download whats my size app from play store and open it

on Top what ever is seen thats the width of the screen

so you can name the layout as

```
layout-sw320dp
```

change the value to what ever is yours

**NOTE:  if you place a folder name with layout-sw320dp and there is no other folder greater than that value then all screens whose small width is greater than 320 will also pick from this folder**

whats ever is xhdpi   thats your screen resolution so you can name drawable folder as

```
drawable-xhdpi
```

replace xhdpi with your resolution

but i cant see why you neeed seperate string,colours?  they will be same for all screens

the values folder can be similar to layout folder like

```
values-sw320dp
```